# Which version of Flutter can I download for Xcode 10.1?

Tags: xcode, flutter, version

My laptop is a MacBook Air mid-2011 so I can't update to Mojave or Catalina (I have High Sierra 10.13.16). The most recent version of Flutter requires the most recent version of Xcode, which I am unable to install. I don't know which version of Flutter is compatible with the version of Xcode I have (10.1).
Thanks!